# discord.js | Remove a role from a member and give said role to another member

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to remove a role from one person, and give that role to the person who initiated the command.

It works the first time, when person A does it. But when someone else tries call the command for the second time, the code doesn't find person A. Any help would be cool.

```js
//Just some startup stuff
const { error, timeStamp } = require('console'),
client = new Discord.Client(),
client.login('How About No?')

var command, role, person

//Check if it's alive
client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log(`${client.user.tag} is online`)
})

//When a message is sent
client.on('message', message => {

command = message.content.toLowerCase()

if(command === 'test' && message.guild.id === 'the server ID'){

    role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.id === 'the role ID') //Find the correct role

    person = role.members.first()
    /* I can use ".first()" here, because there's never supposed to be more than one person with this role.
    The problem is here. On the second run, it outputs "undefined" even though a person has the role. */

    //If a person has the role, remove it from them.
    if(typeof person !== 'undefined') person.roles.remove(role).catch(error => console.log(error))

    //Give the role
    person = message.member
    person.roles.add(role).catch(error => console.log(error))
}

})
```

Answer (score 0):

It can happen sometimes because the cache won't update fast enough.

What you can do is [fetch](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch) the role instead with API request.

```
message.guild.roles.fetch('the role ID',true,true)
```